# How to load multiple component with one route angular

Tags: angular, angular8

I am loading different component on route match.

```js
{
  path: '', component: MainComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      component: ProjectComponent,
    },
    {
      path: "business/:id",
      component: BusinessComponent
    },
    {
      path: "category/:id1/:id2",
      component: CategoryComponent
    },
  ]
}
```

Now I need to add search route where need to show all components as per search match.

How can I show all components(`ProjectComponent`, `BusinessComponent` & `CategoryComponent`) together to display search result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new component for search results and inside this component use all of the other three components.

results template for example

```
<div>
  <!-- any header, page title, search input .... -->

  <app-project></app-project>
  <app-business></app-business>
  <app-category></app-category>

</div>
```

and pass data as inputs if needed